# How to recover data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner on react native. I use Firebase and I would like to retrieve the child `TorchesMigRefroidiesAir` in order to display what it contains.

When I make a `console.log()` it shows me `null`. I do not see how. Could you help me please ? Thank you.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('PostesMig').child('TorchesMigRefroidiesAir')

    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        this.setState({
            postes : snapshot.val(),
            loading: false
        })
    })
}
```

**My json :**

```
{
"PostesMig": [
    {
        "CodeCommun": "6460669",
        "RefFournisseur": "KFM1170001",
        "DesignationAS400": "MINARCMIG EVO 170 T3M COMPLET",
        "TorchesMigRefroidiesAir": [
            {
            "CodeCommun": "6460754",
            "RefFournisseur": "6250220",
            "DesignationAS400": "TORCHE MIG KEMPPI MMG 22 3M"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "CodeCommun": "6460670",
        "RefFournisseur": "KFM1200001",
        "DesignationAS400": "MINARCMIG EVO 200 T3M COMPLET",
        "TorchesMigRefroidiesAir": [
            {
            "CodeCommun": "6460754",
            "RefFournisseur": "6250220",
            "DesignationAS400": "TORCHE MIG KEMPPI MMG 22 3M"
            },
            {
            "CodeCommun": "6460742",
            "RefFournisseur": "102P721030",
            "DesignationAS400": "TORCHE MIG TBI 150 3M EXPERT"
            }
        ]
    },
```

**Picture of my Firebase Database :**

[image: Picture of my Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the data wit: `firebase.database().ref('PostesMig').child('TorchesMigRefroidiesAir')`, which means you're reading the path `/PostesMig/TorchesMigRefroidiesAir`. There is no data at that path, so you get an empty snapshot.

---

There is an **array** of data at `/PostesMig`. If you're looking to load the first child node in that array, that'd be at path: `/PostesMig/0/TorchesMigRefroidiesAir`, so `firebase.database().ref('PostesMig/0/TorchesMigRefroidiesAir')`.

---

If you're looking to read the `` child of each item in the array, that'd be:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('PostesMig');

ref.on('value', snapshot => {
    let results = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      results.push(child.val().TorchesMigRefroidiesAir);
    });
    this.setState({
        postes : results,
        loading: false
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you very much it works.

I would like to display them in a flatList for each position. How can you please?